# Finding joint pdf from marginal

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

X is a continuous rv with the pdf:
$$
f_{X}(x)= \begin{cases}2 x & 1 \geq x \geq 0 \\ 0 & \text { elsewhere }\end{cases}
$$

We know that given X = x , the random variable Y is uniformly distributed on [−x, x].

I need to find the joint PDF and marginal Fy(y).

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Noitece that $Y$ must have values between $-1$ and $1$. Convince yourself that  $E[Y\in A|X=x]=\frac{1}{2x}\int^x_{-x}\mathbb{1}_A(y)\,dy$ for a measurable set $A\subset[-1,1]$. The rest is a little exercise on Fubini's theorem (change of order of integration.